# How to install and configure LispWorks PE on 64bit Linux system?

Tags: development, ide, lisp

**LispWorks Personal Edition** is cross-platform development tool for **Common Lisp**.

I did a small research, looking for any simple installation guide, but I found only [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587850/lispworks-pe-installation-on-ubuntu-14-10-64bit) and [this](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/RNIG/html/readme-27.htm). After following these instructions LispWorks works, but it doesn't follow system-wide GTK theme.

[image: LispWorks PE with default gtk theme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write and share a simple complex guide, how to install and configure LispWorks Personal Edition on Debian-like 64bit systems (amd64 architecture). The procedure will be similar on all other 64bit distributions, but with the use of specific package managers and package names.

If you don't have [sudo](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo) installed, run commands as root.

### 1. Enable [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
```

### 2. Download and install LispWorks

Open [this](http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/index.html) url, fill in the form below, and follow **Installation using tar files**.

Default installation path is `/usr/local/lib/LispWorksPersonal/`.

Installation will **not** create desktop launcher integrated in system. If you need launcher, step 5 in this guide will help you.

### 3. Install dependencies

Following package is necessary for the proper running of the program.

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Next packages allow you change GTK theme for LispWorks.

```
sudo apt install gnome-themes-extra:i386 gtk-chtheme:i386
```

### 4. Choose your system-wide GTK theme

Run this as normal user in terminal:

```
gtk-chtheme
```

and choose theme which you want.

[image]

### 5. Create desktop launcher (optional)

You can use graphic tool likes [Menulibre](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/menulibre) or [Alacarte](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/alacarte) or create launcher by yourself in any text editor. Check [this](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en).

Execution path will be: `/usr/local/lib/LispWorksPersonal/lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux`

### 6. Set icons-only for LispWorks toolbars (optional)

Launch LispWorks and for a better look you can select in top panel **Works** / **Customize** / **Toolbar** and here in **Display** select-box choose **Image**. You must do this for all windows you use. Toolbars will have more compact look.

[image]

### 7. Configure environment (optional)

Go to **Works** / **Tools** / **Preferences** / **Environment** and in the **Emulation** tab choose **Editor keys like KDE/Gnome** and in the **File Encoding** tab select in both left select-boxes **UTF-8**.

---

I'm currently trying to find a way to change the icon-theme in LispWorks.